# Ionic 5 dependencies update bug

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

My Ionic 5 (Angular) Project packages/dependencies were too outdated, so I decided to update all of them at once, most important of which for me were Typescript, Angular and RxJS. I updated all of them to the latest versions. A lot of things seemed to break, not just in the code but also the ionic dependencies not being yet compatible, so I downgraded Angular to version 8. Then I had to fix some of the deprecated syntax in the code but not a big deal.

After fixing a couple of things like that, I get this scss file error:

```
node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/ionicons.scss, line: 9 
         File to import not found or unreadable: ionicons-icons. 
    L9:  @import "ionicons-icons";
   L10:  @import "ionicons-variables";
```

I was looking for a lot of workarounds/fixes for this, but still no progress and my build fails because of this.

Comment: Have you tried to generate a new project? If not, I usually do when I have versions incompatibilities (Angular, Ionic or Typescript) and check what files/dependencies/imports/configs are missing with your current project.

Comment: Which Ionic version were you using before? If it's <5 did you look at the [breaking changes](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/master/BREAKING.md)?